# jQuerys $(document).height() in mootools?

Tags: jquery, mootools, height, document

is there a quick solution with mootools, that acts like the 
    $(document).height()
from jquery?
i just simply need the **real** document height, browser independent.

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the methods you need are in Element.Dimensions: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions

`window.getSize().y` is the viewport height.

`window.getScrollSize().y` is the height of the document including the scrollable hidden area.

Answer (score 1):

The claim that mootools' `.getSize().y` is same as jQuery's `.height()` is false. The [mootools getSize() documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions#Element%3agetSize) states:

> Returns the height and width of the Element, taking into account borders and padding.

But the [jQuery .height() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/) shows that borders and padding are not included. Therefore, this jQuery code will not change the element's height:

```
myElement.height(myElement.height())
```

But this mootools code will change the element's height, unless it has no vertical borders or padding:

```
myElement.setStyle('height', myElement.getSize().y+'px')
```

The correct answer is the [.getComputedSize() method](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Element/Element.Measure#Element%3agetComputedSize). By default .getComputedSize() also includes borders and padding, but unlike .getSize(), it is possible to override that behavior.

```
var elementHeight = myElement.getComputedSize({styles:[]}).totalHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a framework specific thing: can be done in plain JS http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/